Is there a way to make two scatter density plots share the same legend in R
I am using geom_pointdensity() to draw scatter density plot in R. Is there a way to draw them side by side as subplots and also share the same legend with the same range?

Have a look at the {patchwork} package.

In the future, please use a minimal, reproducible example so that we can help you more easily.
Nevertheless, here is an example using the facet_wrap function.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpointdensity)
library(viridis)

# Example dataset
dat <- bind_rows(
  tibble(x = rnorm(7000, sd = 1),
         y = rnorm(7000, sd = 10),
         group = "foo"),
  tibble(x = rnorm(3000, mean = 1, sd = .5),
         y = rnorm(3000, mean = 7, sd = 5),
         group = "bar"))

# Plot figure using facet_wrap
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~group)


Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.1.0
